# How to check if the current task is cancelled in Swift Tasks (async/await)

Tags: swift, async-await, concurrency, swift-concurrency

Why the following code doesn't print "cancelled". Am I checking task cancellation in a wrong way?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private var task: Task<Void, Never>?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let task = Task {
            do {
                try await test()
            } catch {
                if Task.isCancelled {
                    print("cancelled in catch block..")
                }
                if let cancellationError = error as? CancellationError {
                    print("Task canceled..")
                }
            }
        }
        self.task = task
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1)) {
            task.cancel()
        }
    }
    
    func test() async throws {
        while true {
            if Task.isCancelled {
                print("cancelled..")
                throw URLError(.badURL)
            }
            // OUTPUT:
            // "cancelled.." will not be printed
            // "Task canceled.." will not be printed
            // "cancelled in catch block.." will not be printed
        }        
    }
}
```

However, if I put `if Task.isCancelled { print("cancelled in catch block..") }` inside the catch block, `cancelled in catch block..` will be executed as expected.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should avoid GCD API in Swift concurrency codebases. Instead of `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(…) { task.cancel() }`, I would suggest `Task { try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1)); task.cancel() }`.

Comment: Also, FWIW, `catch is CancellationError { … }` is another way to check the error type. See https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/135c2d816ebb00aeb5f18964c11d4fd8.

Comment: You need add to the logs call of the task cancellation, then you will see that it's actually not called.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks @Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most significant problem here is that the view controller is isolated to `@MainActor`, so `test` is isolated to the main actor, too. But this function proceeds to spin quickly, with no suspension points (i.e., no `await`), so you are indefinitely blocking the main actor. Therefore, you are blocking the main thread, too, and thus never even reaching your `task.cancel()` line.

To solve this, you can either:

1. Move `test` off the main actor:

   ```swift
   nonisolated func test() async throws { … }
   ```

   A `nonisolated` method that is `async` will not run on the current actor. See [SE-0338](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0338-clarify-execution-non-actor-async.md).

   (Note, getting it off the main actor is, at best, only a partial solution, as you really should never block *any* of the threads in the Swift concurrency cooperative thread pool. But more on that later.)

   Or,
2. Use the non-blocking `Task.sleep` in your loop (which introduces an `await` suspension point) instead of a tightly spinning loop. This would avoiding the blocking of the main actor, and transform it to something that just periodically checks for cancelation:

   ```swift
   func test() async throws {
       while true {
           try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(0.5))
           try Task.checkCancellation()

           // or
           //
           // try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(0.5))
           // if Task.isCancelled {
           //     print("cancelled..")
           //     throw CancellationError()       // very misleading to throw URLError(.badURL) !!!
           // }
       }
   }
   ```

   Actually, because `Task.sleep` actually already checks for cancellation, you don’t need `checkCancellation` or an `isCancelled` test, at all:

   ```swift
   func test() async throws {
       while true {
           try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(0.5))
       }
   }
   ```

Never have long-running synchronous code (like your `while` loop) in Swift concurrency. We have a contract with Swift concurrency to never block the current actor (especially the main actor).

See [SE-0296](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0296-async-await.md), which says:

> Asynchronous functions should avoid calling functions that can actually block the thread…

Or see WWDC 2021 video [Swift concurrency: Behind the scenes](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10254?time=730)

> We want you to be able to write straight-line code that is easy to reason about and also gives you safe, controlled concurrency. In order to achieve this behavior that we are after, the operating system needs a runtime contract that threads will not block …
>
> And lastly, the final consideration has to do with the runtime contract that is foundational to the efficient threading model in Swift. Recall that with Swift, the language allows us to uphold a runtime contract that threads will always be able to make forward progress. … As you adopt Swift concurrency, it is important to ensure that you continue to maintain this contract in your code as well so that the cooperative thread pool can function optimally. …

Bottom line, if `test` is really is a time-consuming spinning on the CPU like your example, you would:

- get it off the main actor;
- periodically `try Task.checkCancellation()`; and also
- periodically call `try Task.yield()`.

But I must acknowledge the possibility that this `while` loop was introduced when preparing your example (because it really is a bit of an edge-case). If, for example, `test` is really just calling some `async` function that handles cancelation (e.g., a network call), then none of this silliness of manually checking for cancelation is generally needed. It would not block the main actor, and likely already handles cancelation. We would need to see what `test` really is doing to advise further.

---

Setting aside the idiosyncrasies of the code snippet, in answer to your original question, “How to check if the current task is cancelled?”, there are four basic approaches:

1. Call `async throws` functions that already support cancellation. Most of Apple’s `async throws` functions natively support cancellation, e.g., `Task.sleep`, `URLSession` functions, etc. And if writing your own `async` function, use any of the techniques outlined in the following three points.
2. Use `withTaskCancellationHandler(operation:onCancel:)` to wrap your
   cancelable asynchronous process.

   This is useful when calling a cancelable legacy API and wrapping it in a `Task`. This way, canceling a task can proactively stop the asynchronous process in your legacy API, rather than waiting until you reach a manual `checkCancellation` call.
3. When we are performing some manual, computationally-intensive process with a loop, we would just `try Task.checkCancellation()`. But all the previously mention caveats about not blocking threads, yielding, etc., still apply.
4. Alternatively, you can test `Task.isCancelled`, and if so, manually throw `CancellationError`. This is the most cumbersome approach, but it works.

Many discussions about handling cooperative cancelation tend to dwell on these latter two approaches, but when dealing with legacy cancelable API, the aforementioned `withTaskCancellationHandler` is generally the better solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, this makes sense and I completely forgot this is blocking my main thread so my cancel() never got a chance to run. And yes as you mentioned, this code snippet is just for my own testing purpose to understand how async works.

I do have another QQ though: will using "await" always create a suspension point?For example, what is the behavior of `await print("1")`? I know it will not check cancellation for you, but wondering will it really create a suspension point at its core, and will the thread ever be different before vs after running this code?

Comment: If you attempt to `await` something that is not asynchronous, the compiler will generate a warning to that effect. If we wanted to introduce a suspension point in the middle of some synchronous code (e.g., to give other tasks a chance to run), we might reach for `await Task.yield()`. Re thread before and after suspension point, no, you have no assurance that it will necessarily be the same thread (except main actor). FWIW, the same is true with GCD serial queues, that you have no assurances that two items dispatched to same serial queue will run on the same thread.

Comment: @ShuaiqingLuo – By the way, the aforementioned WWDC video, [Swift concurrency: Behind the scenes](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10254/?time=1392), is an excellent primer on these topics and says, “Swift makes no guarantee that the thread which executed the code before the await is the same thread which will pick up the continuation as well.” Also, the Swift evolution proposals (e.g., [SE-0296 – async/await](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0296-async-await.md), etc.) contain lots of interesting implementation details.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. Just to confirm my understanding: Using `await` alone will not create suspension point for sure, because we can write things like `await print()`

Comment: I cannot say that “for sure”, but I suspect it would *not* constitute a suspension point. You theoretically could look at the disassembly if you really wanted to know (though that it is notoriously hard to decipher). But, even if it did introduce a suspension point (which, again, I would be skeptical of that), I am not sure I would want to ever rely on that behavior as an `await` of non-asynchronous code could easily be a NOP in future releases.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you Rob!!

Comment: Hi @Rob, I have one more question about what thread we will be on after an await. I was reading [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/swift/5.5/structured-concurrency#:~:text=As%20an%20alternative%2C%20you%20can,was%20added%20successfully%20or%20not.) that ` printFibonacciSequence() function will continue running on whichever thread it was while the Fibonacci numbers are being calculated.` Do you think this statement is correct? Doesn't this mean we actually can know what thread we have after an await, which will be the same thread as how the awaited async function exits.

Comment: @ShuaiqingLuo – Paul generally has excellent content, but in this case, he is running fast and loose in his terminology (and these particular examples aren’t great). One could even argue that it is a mistake to even use the word “thread” at all. It is best to stop thinking in terms of threads! FWIW, Apple is completely unambiguous on this point: With the exception of the main actor, you have no assurances as to which thread the continuation (i.e., the code after an `await` suspension point) uses.

Comment: Note, the choice of thread for the continuation is not arbitrary. They’re not just randomizing threads to keep us on our toes. Lol. It is an elegant performance optimization designed to mitigate unnecessary, costly context switches. So, this begs the question as to why you would want it to forgo these optimizations just for the sake of getting the continuation back on the same thread as before the `await` suspension point. Swift concurrency efficiently achieves thread-safety without imposing any requirements that it must be on the original thread.

Comment: It begs the question as to why you care what thread the continuation uses.

Comment: Oh it's more of me trying to learn what is its actual behavior. Re- "with the exception of the main actor", do you mean if an async function is exited on MainActor, then we can know for sure the code after `await` will also run on main thread?

Comment: Yep. Actors will generally avail themselves of any thread from the cooperative thread pool. But the main actor can only run on the main thread. It is the exception to the rule.

Comment: But why is this an exception for `MainActor`. I feel like if we are doing it for Main Thread, then it should also be the case for other threads. Wondering where did Apple document this: `With the exception of the main actor, you have no assurances as to which thread the continuation (i.e., the code after an await suspension point) uses.` Thanks!

Comment: I’m have already shared quotes from Apple docs re the continuation may use a different thread. Re the main actor, that is just a constraint unique to that particular actor, that it always uses the main thread. But that is the only actor that imposes that constraint. And again, the question is not why aren’t all actors running their continuations on the same thread but rather why in the world would you want to introduce that overhead/inefficiency…